# Hiding controls overlay in mediaplayer framework, sdk4 iphone xcode

Tags: xcode4

I am building a simple & basic video app using the media player framework.

How do I hide the player control overlay in SDK4, xcode so that the user does not have access to *play, pause, ff, rw*, etc.?

The codes I have implemented simply do not work and either give errors or do nothing at all.
I am stumped and have not been able to find support via research.  I also need to take care of a memory leak later.

I've tried:

```
-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender
{
    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1960" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]         initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [moviePlayerController play];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Video1" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];

moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(38, 100, 250, 163)];
moviePlayerController.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

`yourPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;`

and change yourPlayer to your name of the player.